# Access TortoiseSVN local repository from another boot on the same machine?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, multiboot

Is there a way to access the local TortoiseSVN repository from another OS on the same machine?

When I try to access it from another OS, I get "Unable to Unable to open an ra_local session to URL" error.
Do I have to setup the SVN sever?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a local URL with a full path like this:

```
file:///full/path/to/repository
```

Note the 3 slashs ('/') after the protocol identifier('file:').

On windows it comes down to:

```
file:///d:/full/path/to/repo
```

(No backslash in URL!!)

Needless to say that you need correct SVN versions on both machines.
There is no permissions system. You can read and write the full repository file structure(you have full file access anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you really ought to set up a proper SVN server on another system. You will need to ensure that you keep SVN versions in sync between OSes otherwise.